# passport facebook authentication is not providing email address

Tags: node.js, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

i did all ways that are explained in Stackoverflow but it didn't work

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 'CLIENT ID',
    clientSecret: 'CLIENT SECRET',
    callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback",
    profileFields:['id', 'emails', 'link', 'locale', 'name',
  'timezone', 'updated_time', 'verified', 'displayName']
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile);
    var authId = 'facebook:' + profile.id;   
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      var user = users[i];
      if(user.authId === authId){   
        return done(null, user);
      }
    }

    var new_user = {
      'authId':authId,
      'displayName':profile.displayName
    };
    users.push(new_user);
    done(null, new_user);
  }
));
```

and

```
app.get(
  '/auth/facebook',
   passport.authenticate(
     'facebook',
     {scope:['email']}
   )
 );
```

but in my console

```
 _json:
   { id: 'MY ID',
     link: 'https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/MY_ID/',
     locale: 'ko_KR',
     last_name: 'LAST_NAME',
     first_name: 'FIRST_NAME',
     timezone: 9,
     updated_time: '2016-06-26T06:25:28+0000',
     verified: true,
     name: 'MY NAME' } }
```

there are no email fields what is problem?
or is there any problem in my facebook account authorization?

Answer (score 0):

in the profileFields object, use 'email' instead of 'emails.

```
profileFields:['id', 'emails', 'link', 'locale', 'name',
  'timezone', 'updated_time', 'verified', 'displayName']
```

replace with

```
profileFields:['id', 'email', 'link', 'locale', 'name',
  'timezone', 'updated_time', 'verified', 'displayName']
```

Comment: thank you for your comment ! but it doesn't work...:( i don't know why...!! same situation

Comment: I tried the same and it was working, dont know whats wrong there

Comment: i think there is some problems in my facebook account authorization i will check it.  Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: create test users by ur facebook developer account and also test on them

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: 'CLIENT ID',
    clientSecret: 'CLIENT SECRET',
    callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback",
    profileFields:['id', 'emails', 'link', 'locale', 'name',
  'timezone', 'updated_time', 'verified', 'displayName']
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile.emails[0].value);
    var authId = 'facebook:' + profile.id;   
    for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
      var user = users[i];
      if(user.authId === authId){   
        return done(null, user);
      }
    }

    var new_user = {
      'authId':authId,
      'displayName':profile.displayName
    };
    users.push(new_user);
    done(null, new_user);
  }
));
```

and

```
app.get(
  '/auth/facebook',
   passport.authenticate(
     'facebook',
     {scope:['public_profile', 'email']}
   )
 );
```